# How to deserialize a file containing multiple records

Tags: c++, deserialization, offset, thrift

i've written a thrift-definition, and used this defintion to serialize multiple records in one file (i've added the size of the whole record at the beginning of each record). That is in short what I have done.

```
boost::shared_ptr<apache::thrift::transport::TMemoryBuffer> transport(new apache::thrift::transport::TMemoryBuffer);
boost::shared_ptr<apache::thrift::protocol::TBinaryProtocol> protocol(new apache::thrift::protocol::TBinaryProtocol(transport));

myClass->write(protocol.get());

const std::string & data(transport->getBufferAsString());
```

Afterwards i just print the string data in binary mode. Now I want to deserialize this file again. I wouldn't have any problem if there was only on record in the file, unfortunately I have to print multiple files, so I guess I have to work with offset based on the size i saved in the file along with the record itself. However, I can't seem to find any example I can use to achieve my goals, and the official documentation is quite lacking. Has anyone any tipps for me. If I'm missing some information, just ask.

Further Informations:

Of course I want to use use thrift to deserialize. However, one file can contain multiple records. For example: Imagine I have defined a struct in a thrift-definition file that contains car-Information. Now I serialize multiple car-structs in one output file. Serializing is no problem as i just append the data. If i want to deserialize however, I have to know where one record starts, and the next begins. That is my problem. I don't know how to tell thrift where one record begins and ends. I've searched the internet, but can't seem to find an example for c++ (i got one for python so far, but am not able to translate it to c++). The structure of one file can be described as followed: [lenghtofrecord1][record1][lengthofrecord2][record2][...]

Thanks in Advance

Michael

Comment: I'm probably missing the point, but can't you just use thrift to deserialize?  As far as I understand, thrift is symmetrical and aware of containers of structs (see https://thrift.apache.org/docs/types/)

Comment: I've added information to my question, I hope it is more clear now.

Comment: Maybe I found a solution, still have to test it though.

Answer (score 2):

How about having a `list<records>` that you de/serialize as a whole? Or is it an absolute requirement to read them independently and randomly? If yes, I see 1,5 (one and a half) possible solutions:

- Have a second file as an index. This holds a `map< recordNumber, offset>`, or simply a sorted list of integers-pairs, to quickly locate records. Since these data are much less than the records you probably can cache it in memory all the time.
- The half solution: iff the record size is fixed, any records position could be calculated easily by multiplying `recordSize * (recordNr-1)`. This way you don't even need the size prefix. If you have strings in the record or other variable-sized entities, this will not work, unless you force a fixed record size by reserving a buffer for each record with a predefined (maximum) size. It's a little ugly, thus the "half" solution, but you don't need the index file.

Answer (score 0):

Although maybe not the perfect solution, this seems to work for me:

```
    boost::shared_ptr<apache::thrift::transport::TMemoryBuffer> transport(new apache::thrift::transport::TMemoryBuffer);
    boost::shared_ptr<apache::thrift::protocol::TBinaryProtocol> protocol(new apache::thrift::protocol::TBinaryProtocol(transport));
    transport->resetBuffer((uint8_t*) buffer, sizeOfEntry);
```

Buffer is a char array containing the desired record (I used seekg for the offset) and sizeOfEntry is the records size. Afterwards I can go on with the automatically generated read-Method of my thrift-generated class. In Fact I had this solution earlier, I just messed up my offset, thus it didn't work.